# Android: Trying to get list of objects from server and display in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, calendar, adapter

Fair to say, IM a n00by..

**I am trying to get a list of object from server and display in listview.** I have an adapter that sends a request to the server (jar for now) and returns it. I have a fragment the connects the view and the adapter but I am doing something wrong.

I have a feeling it has something to do **how** I am calling `getDayItems()` in `onSelectedDayChange(...)` or/and because of maybe mixed List/ArrayList in different places. But I am not a judge.

About the **picking the date**, the server doesn´t take any variables at the moment, it should just give me a list if some date is clicked.

Here is the fragment..

```
    public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

      private ArrayList<CalanderMeal> calMeals = new ArrayList<CalanderMeal>();
      private ListView listView;
      private CalendarView calendarView;
      private CalendarAdapter adapter;
      private View parentView;
      private int yearSelected; //year selected by user
      private int monthSelected; //month selected by user
      private int dayOfMonthSelected; //day of month selected by user

      public static FragmentA newInstance(String text){
          FragmentA f = new FragmentA();

          return f;
      }

      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        calendarView = (CalendarView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
        listView = (ListView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.dailyView1);

        /*
        adapter = new CalendarAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_a, calMeals);
        ListView listview = (ListView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.dailyView1);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        */

        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                yearSelected = year;
                monthSelected = month;
                dayOfMonthSelected = dayOfMonth;

                calMeals = (ArrayList<CalanderMeal>) adapter.getDayItems();

                adapter = new CalendarAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_a, calMeals);
                ListView listview = (ListView)parentView.findViewById(R.id.dailyView1);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

        return parentView;
     }
    }
```

And here is the adapter..

```
public class CalendarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CalanderMeal> {


    private ArrayList<CalanderMeal> mCalList;
    private CalendarService calService;

    public CalendarAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID,     
                   ArrayList<CalanderMeal> calList){
        super(context, layoutResourceID, calList);
        this.mCalList = calList;
}

public List<CalanderMeal> getDayItems(){

    List<CalanderMeal> calList;
    calService = CalendarServiceFactory.getCalanderService();
    calList = calService.getMealsByDay();

    return calList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return  mCalList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you specify what the issue your having is ?

Answer (score 0):

Your getView method is returning null - how do you expect to see any results visually ?